# List<DayOfWeek> in localized order

Tags: java, dayofweek, java-time

We have the [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum defining the days of the week in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) order.

I want a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) of those objects in the order appropriate to a [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html).

We can easily determine the first day of the week for locale.

```
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;
DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek =  WeekFields.of( locale ).getFirstDayOfWeek() ;
```

Set up the `List`.

```
List< DayOfWeek > dows = new ArrayList<>( 7 ) ;  // Set initial capacity to 7, for the seven days of the week.
dows.add( firstDayOfWeek ) ;
```

➥ To add the other six days of the week to that list, what is the simplest/shortest/most elegant approach?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`plus`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#plus-long-) method of `DayOfWeek`.

> The calculation rolls around the end of the week from Sunday to Monday.

Increment numbers with [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) and its [`range`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range(int,int)) method (*inclusive* start, *exclusive* end).

```
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH;
DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek = WeekFields.of(locale).getFirstDayOfWeek();

List<DayOfWeek> dows = IntStream.range(0, 7)
        .mapToObj(firstDayOfWeek::plus)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Perfect. I never noticed that method. That beats `( ( firstDayOfWeek.getValue() + i - 1 ) % 7 + 1 )` in a `for ( int i = 0 ; i < 7 ; i++ )` loop.

Answer (score 0):

My solution in Kotlin:

```
fun sortedDaysOfWeek(locale: Locale = Locale.getDefault()): List<DayOfWeek> {
     val firstDayOfWeek = WeekFields.of(locale).firstDayOfWeek

     return DayOfWeek.values().partition { it == firstDayOfWeek }
                              .let{ it.first + it.second }
}
```